# Display special characters in C

Tags: c

I have an requirement where the C code extract string data from database and write it to a file. The string data in the database can have any kind of characters

**for example:** Description field have data  **"Adj \342\200\223 Data"** , when I write to the file the text it writes as **"Adj â Data"**. Similarly, this description field can have any kind of data, my code just read and uses **strcpy** after extracting from the database and write to a file.

How do I get the data written to a file as it is in the description field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think easiest solution would be writing byte by byte - shouldn't matter that much with buffering:

```
int pos = 0;
FILE *fp = 0;
//...
fp = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
//...
while(buffer[pos])
    if(buffer[pos] < 32 || buffer[pos] > 127) // change bounds for non-printable chars as you like
        fprintf(fp, "%c", buffer[pos++]);
    else
        fprintf(fp, "\\%u", buffer[pos++]);
```

Edit:
Might have misunderstood your question. Only use string functions when you're actually working with strings. For binary data use binary functions (e.g. the mentioned `memcpy()`).

Edit 2/3:
Don't print the value as "%d" or "%u" - should be "%3o" to print as a 3-digit octal number. Using "%o" could be unsafe if other digits follow.

Comment: Beat me to the punch, but this is a pretty good solution. As a note to the asker, If you want to write to a file, you can also use fprintf, and the first argument becomes FILE*, such that one can do fprintf(file, "%c", buffer[pos++]); - this way you don't need to jumble around with string printing or anything.

Comment: Well performance is also one thing that I need to consider, as I will be extracting huge amount of data and I cannot be running to through each field and each character to fix this , kindly advise.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. If you just want to write the data to a file and be able to read that back, no need to "escape" any non-printable characters or whatever. If what I'm actually doing is what you're looking for, I don't think there's any faster way (as any implementation would walk through character by character). You could use an additional buffer but file caching should make that rather obsolete.

Comment: @dicarprio: At least try to make sure you don't need it to be any faster. Going through each character likely won't cause a problem; it's the invocation of printf that might hurt you. However, I'm really not sure if writing out the octals yourself will really be all that much better. Maybe you should give it a test run to be sure?

Comment: Crap, yet another note to make: The string in the example is in octal form, not decimal form. That means, in place of %d, you need to be doing %o.

Comment: @All, in fact , I don't write it file directly, I doing this code under a frame work , In which I just have to convert the string to buffer and frame work will take care of writing to a file. In this case these fields have lot of special character, not necessarily the octal , which I have shown just as an example, it can have any kind of data , any special character.

Comment: @Mario: Thanks much , this piece of code I have in mind, but only worry is performance and these fields can have a data of 100 characters. I have to write something generic.

Comment: 100 characters are nothing unless you're executing it on a calculator. ;) Just test it. @John, oh, right, you're correct. @dicaprio: Are you sure your framework requires the escaped form? Or are you messing compile time strings and runtime data?

Comment: @Mario: Yes it requires escaped form. It just convert to buffer and write to file.